# how to create a procedure for validating user login

Tags: plsql

how to create a procedure for validating  user login

The procedure header is 
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_user_login

(

user_id NUMBER,

password    VARCHAR2,

out_c OUT NUMBER

)
if the userid is not in the user_id column of the USER table then assign -1 to out_c parameter.

The value of userid is in the USER_ID column of the USER table, but the corresponding account is locked out(IS_LOCKED_OUT = 'Y'). You assign -2 to the out_code parameter.

Can anyone please help me with the logic. i am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Just checking - is this just an exercise for educational purposes? (please say yes)

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for here. You have the "logic" already in the question. Are you looking for help on how to check if the user is in the USERS table, and/or how to check if an account is locked?

Comment: yes its an assignment. i want some help to check if the user id is in the users tables.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Could I get an upvote for my answer, please?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
create or replace procedure check_user_login(p_user_id number, p_password varchar2, p_out_c OUT number)
is
  v_account_status varchar2(255);
begin

  p_out_c := 0; 

  select account_status
  into v_account_status
  from dba_users
  where user_id = p_user_id
  and password = p_password;

  if v_account_status like '%LOCKED%' then
    p_out_c := -2;
  end if;

  exception
    when no_data_found then
      p_out_c := -1;

end check_user_login;
```